# Recursively get a list of users [Firebase + Saga]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga

As Firebase’s Firestore only allows 10 items at each query. I need to recursively query users in batches of 10 users.

This is what I've done referencing from [Composing Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ComposingSagas.html)
, but `users` returns a list of `undefined`. What have I done wrong? Or is there a better (more efficient) way to query a list of users from Firestore? Note: I have to use Redux-Saga.

```js
export function* watchGetListUsersByUids() {
  yield takeEvery(USERS_GET_USERS_BY_UIDS, getListUsersByUids);
}

const getListUsersByUidsAsync = async (list_uid, set) => {
  var get_uids = list_uid.slice(set * 10, (set + 1) * 10);
  console.log("get_uids", get_uids);
  await firestore
    .collection("users")
    .where("uid", "in", get_uids)
    .get()
    .then((data) => data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
    .catch((error) => error);
};

function* getListUsersByUids({ payload }) {
  const { uids } = payload;

  var numSet = parseInt(uids.length / 10);

  var apiCalls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= numSet; i++) {
    apiCalls.push(call(getListUsersByUidsAsync, uids, i));
  }

  if (apiCalls.length) {
    try {
      const users = yield all(apiCalls);
      console.log(users); // <-- [undefined, undefined, ...]
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any errors while running the code? in browser console, network tab, do you see any network calls happening? are they resulting 200 success status? before trying to fetch all users at once, were you able to get first 10 users without recursive approach?

Comment: this code will immediately execute call, the return data from call is pushed to the array
  for (var i = 0; i <= numSet; i++) {
    apiCalls.push(call(getListUsersByUidsAsync, uids, i));
  }